# How to style a react component correctly?

Tags: reactjs

I am using react with a plain old css file. If I have a component  I would like to be able to set it's position by adding  then adding a margin to it. This isn't working for me though. Right now I can only put a  around the component then style the div. I want to stack like 6 of the same  components on top of each other so altering the style inside of component wouldn't work. What should I do here?

Comment: You can style any component using `<MyComponent style={{margin: "2px", ...}}>` or `<MyComponent className="...">`.

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#style)?

Comment: When I style <MyComponent style = {{margin: "200px}} /> nothing happens

Comment: @PurplePanda in your example `<MyComponent style = {{margin: "200px}} />` ^ you're missing quotes after px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to add a class name passed as a property something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyComponent className="some-class" />
                <MyComponent className="another-class" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root');
```

Then, in `MyComponent` you can add that class name to the `div` like this:

```
import React from 'react';

export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={ this.props.className }></div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: glad to help. The same would work for a `style` attribute too.